# Security Context issue - querying from tables with different authentications?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, authentication

I need to union records from two databases on the same server; **one db uses SQL Server authentication, the other Windows authentication.**

I've successfully queried from both tables individually, but the union query generates the following error:

```
USER not able to access the database "WindowsAuthDB" under the current security context.
```

My understanding is that the query instance only uses one authentication, but accessing both tables requires both SQL Server and Windows authentications.

Is there a method for accessing two tables with different authentications in a single query? Or even in a single Stored Procedure? Or is this an entirely different problem?

Comment: Simple solution to ask DBA to give asscees to both database with **windows authentication** then union both select on one query.

Comment: The suggestions from Hiten004 and Aram are good... or, instead of using UNION, can you put the results into a table (even a temp table)?  If so, then will it allow you to do a `SELECT ... INTO #procsTempTable...` for one query, then `INSERT INTO #procsTempTable... SELECT...` for the other query?  Then you would end with a `SELECT... FROM #procsTempTable` for your final result.

Comment: Rather than force everyone else to convert to Windows Auth on the existing db, the DBA chose to make the new DB use SQL Server login.
Each query instance can apparenlty only use a single login based on the USE context.. which means I would need one query using the Win Auth login to pull the data to a table on a SQL Auth db, and a second query to concatenate the data on the SQL Auth db. 
Seems there ought to be a more elegant way to work with data on dbs with different login methods.

Answer (score 0):

- You can ask for permission from your DBA 
  Or
- if they don't want to do that for any reason you might be able to use the EXEC OPENDATASOURCE command to query external data sources, you still need the Username and Password for doing that though...